# How to move custom code into template.php

Tags: theming

In my node.tpl.php file I have this custom code:

```
<?php if($node->field_division['und'][0]['value'] = 1): 
    $cta = $GLOBALS['base_url'].'/node/6';
elseif($node->field_division['und'][0]['value'] = 2): 
    $cta = $GLOBALS['base_url'].'/node/7';
endif;
?>
```

I want to move it to my template.php file, so I can access it both from node.tpl.php and page.tpl.php.

How can I do this?

I tried following the examples in this [thread](http://drupal.org/node/1054548) and this [article](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/theming-best-practices-garland-gets-a-cleanup) but I can't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, [don't use `'und'`](http://www.davereid.net/content/hlkd7fotw-field-get-items). You should use [`field_get_items()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/field_get_items). This is a change from D6, which is likely why you can't use those articles as a reference.

Secondly, you are using `=` and not `==`, so you're assigning the value instead of comparing it.

So, you can probably just do the following:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  THEMENAME_field_division_helper($variables);
}

function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  THEMENAME_field_division_helper($variables);
}

function THEMENAME_field_division_helper(&$variables) {
  if ($node = $variables['node']) {
    $field_division = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_division');
    if ($field_division[0]['tid'] == 1) {
      $variables['cta'] = $GLOBALS['base_url'].'/node/6';
    }
    else if ($field_division[0]['tid'] == 2) {
      $variables['cta'] = $GLOBALS['base_url'].'/node/6';
    }
  }
}
```

And then in your node.tpl.php and page.tpl.php file,

```
<?php if (isset($cta)): ?>
  <div class="some-wrapper">
    <?php print $cta; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I tried it but it doesn't work. When $cta is placed in page.tpl/node/tpl, it doesn't print anything. I have tried clearing the cache and disabling and reinstalling the cache, but no success. Just to double check, the three functions go in template.php, right?

Comment: Yes, they do. You did change THEMENAME to your theme's name, right?

Comment: Yes, I had changed THEMENAME to the theme's name. I also cleared the cache and disabled the the theme, set Bartik as the default, re-enabled the theme and then cleared the cache again to be on the safe side. However, despite all of this $cta doesn't print anything.  I would be very grateful for any help you could offer.

Comment: Well, that means that field_division is never equal to 1 or 2, or it's using a database column other than 'value'. Enable the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and check the node to see where the value is actually being stored.

Comment: Field_division is a taxonomy reference field. When I click it on it Devel, I get "field_division > und > 0 > tid" The value is then 1 or 2 depending on the node.  Essentially, I'm just trying to change the path to a link depending on the term applied. Is using a reference field the best way of doing this?

Comment: I've updated the code, switching 'value' to 'tid'. Should work now.

Comment: Thanks. Not only does that work, but I understand more how to convert my other custom codes into template code. Thanks!  However, is there a way to test the taxonomy term being used on a page that doesn't have a taxonomy reference field? For example, the main www.mysite.com/taxonomy/term/[tid] page? Thanks!